# How to pass a result between methods in Java

Tags: java

Im in CS 1301 and I am struggling with some homework. I am trying to pass the parameter result to the final method so I can just write result instead of 42, and its not recognizing it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class ICalledYou
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ProductNumber();
    ProductBinary();

}
public static void ProductNumber()
{
    Double x = 7.00;
    Double y = 6.00;
    Double result = y*x;
    System.out.println(result);
}
public static void ProductBinary()
{
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(result));
}
```

}

Comment: `result` is a local variable, so its scope is limited to the `ProductNumber` method.  Try researching method parameters and return values, and be sure to include your research in your post if you're still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The method `public static void ProductBinary()` does not take a parameter. Change that,

```
public static void ProductBinary(double result)
```

Second

```
ProductBinary();
```

Isn't passing a parameter, change that

```
ProductBinary(42.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change ProductNumber to *return* the result, then pass that to the other method:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double result = ProductNumber();
    ProductBinary(result);

}
public static double ProductNumber()
{
    Double x = 7.00;
    Double y = 6.00;
    Double result = y*x;
    return result;
}
public static void ProductBinary(double number)
{
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(number));
}
```